# Stream PDF to new browser instance or tab?

Tags: pdf, streaming, response

I want to Stream a PDF to a new browser instance. I currently have this

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=""" & Path.GetFileName(pdfFile) & """")
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length)
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray())
Response.Flush()
```

But this takes over my existing window and navigates me away from the page. I want to spawn a new tab or window and display the PDF there.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Most people prefer a download.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider the [`<a>` target attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp). You can use this to open the PDF in a new Window, perhaps using something like:

```
<a href="GeneratePdf.ashx?somekey=10" target="_blank">
```

Update- as you have now said that you don't mind whether it is in a browser window or not, my preferred technique is to change the content disposition to attachment as per MercerTraieste answer.

If you are using ASP.NET, it is definitely a good idea to consider writing a custom HttpHandler to stream the PDF for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could force a download, this kinda solves youur problem:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename""" & Path.GetFileName(pdfFile) & """")
```

Comment: That's how I normally send PDFs to the client. Though technically it will open directly in Acrobat if you the open option is selected, which isn't a new browser window.

However it is still my preferred solution so +1.

Comment: see my comments to musicfreak. A new requirement is to not first save the PDF.

Comment: I actually think this is fine. It didn't need to really open in a browser. It just needed to be opened and readable on the client without navigating them away from the current page.